# Why my loopback address is ::1 instead of 127.0.0.1 ?

Tags: php

This is not working, it doesn't throw me any errors too

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1') {
  //My code
}
//NOTE: echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is "::1"
```

Comment: try `echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`. What does it output?

Comment: @STTLCU It echo's `::1`, but why?

Comment: I've slightly edited your question, with a title that's more receptive than "why does this not work?"

Comment: server is configured to handle internal stuff with ipv6 instead of 4.

Comment: Well then the solution is simple `if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1' || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '::1')`

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV am fine with 1 condition, it was just that i got confused why that simple thing was not working

Comment: @AcidicCloud Well to make it somehow portable you should use 2 conditions ...

Comment: @AcidicCloud next time avoid writing questions with titles like "why this does not work?" consider a question like a function, use descriptive names whenever possible. It really shows a lot more involvement by the opener rather than a bad smell of "debug this for me asap" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks fine in your code, Try this and see, if it's IPv6, this should work

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '::1') {
   //Your Code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you got ::1 is that you are using ipv6. Turn it off or have both 127.0.0.1 and ::1 in your statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '::1' || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1') {
   //Your Code
}
```

this should make it safe even if you migrate to another server.

as stated before, server is configured to handle it with ipv6 address and ::1 is the ipv6 equivalent of 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

because you're in local host:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1' || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '::1') {
  //Your code
}
```